# SRID mismatch while loading in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, grib

I have a grib2 file from GFS.  I tried to load it as a raster like so...

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 example.grib2 warp_example.grib2
raster2pgsql -I -C -M -d warp_example.grib2 table | psql $database
```

This appears to load correctly.
I try to query it but I get a SRID mismatch error.  This same procedure worked for many other grib files, so I don't understand what is broken in this case.

```
postgres=#  SELECT rid, ST_Value(rast,1, foo.pt_geom) As b1pval FROM surface CROSS JOIN (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(84.1, 39.1), 4326) As pt_geom) As foo WHERE rid=1;
ERROR:  Raster and geometry do not have the same SRID
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_value(raster,integer,geometry,boolean) line 13 at RAISE
```

How do I correct this error?